# How can I create a search box that only searches within a table in a wiki page in Confluence?

Tags: search, confluence

I have very long table with 2 columns:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Word 1 | Blahblah 1 |
| Word 2 | Blahblah 2 |
| Word 3 | Blahblah 3 |
| Word 4 | Blahblah 4 |

I'd like to hide it and instead ask the user to type a word in a box to search for the matching row. If the user types `Word 3`, then they'll see `Blahblah 3`.

How can I do that in a wiki page in Confluence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible create a search box that only searches within a table in a wiki page in Confluence. Confluence doesn't have this feature.